# Serialize a derived type without the type and namespace attributes

Tags: c#, serialization, inheritance

I have an xml API that I have to mimic character for character. I'm trying to use the built-in xml serialization functionality in .NET, but it's adding some extra attributes. In a NORMAL web service or xml API, these attributes wouldn't hurt anything and might even serve a purpose. But they are unexpected characters and, unfortunately, I cannot allow them. So here's what I'd like to do (with hypothetical objects of course):

I have a base type

`public abstract class Instrument { }`

...and I have a derived type

`public class Guitar : Instrument { }`

...and I would like to serialize the derived type to something like this:

`<Guitar />`

Instead, I get this:

`<Instrument d1p1:type="Guitar" xmlns:d1p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />`

Here's a test I'm working with:

```
[TestClass]
public class when_serializing_a_guitar
{
    private XmlSerializer _serializer;
    private string _expectedXml;
    private StringWriter _stringWriter;
    private string _actualXml;
    private XmlSerializerNamespaces _ns;
    private XmlWriter _xmlWriter;

    private void WithThisContext()
    {
        _ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        _ns.Add("", "");

        _stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        _xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(_stringWriter, new XmlWriterSettings
                                                         {
                                                             OmitXmlDeclaration = true,
                                                             CloseOutput = false
                                                         });

        _serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Instrument), new[] { typeof(Guitar) });

        _expectedXml = @"<Guitar />";
    }

    private void BecauseOfThisAction()
    {
        _serializer.Serialize(_xmlWriter, new Guitar(), _ns);
        _actualXml = _stringWriter.ToString();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void it_should_return_the_expected_properly_formatted_xml()
    {
        WithThisContext();
        BecauseOfThisAction();
        Assert.AreEqual(_expectedXml, _actualXml);
    }
}
```

Know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you need to keep the domain model hierarchy intact. Otherwise you could just do this: var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Guitar));

If you do need to keep it intact, I suggest you write your own ToXml methods on each of your domain objects.

```
public interface IXmlWritable
{
    string ToXml();
}

public class Instrument : IXmlWritable
{
    public string classification { get; set; }

    public string ToXml()
    {
        return "<Instrument classification='" + classification + "' />";
    }
}
```

Or something like that depending on how you want to iterate through the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XElement from System.Xml.Linq (you need to add the reference to it with 'add reference'). This is the code to simply create a clean xml doc:

```
XElement el = new XElement("data", new XElement("guitar"));

el.Save(@"D:\test.xml", SaveOptions.None);
```

Comment: Guitar and Instrument were only simplified examples. The real objects are much more complex. The object here is to serialize an object to xml... not just to create an xml node.